# Status 503 in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, configuration

I get the status 503 error when running the elasticsearch. It was working fine till yesterday, suddenly i am getting this error now.

```
{
 status: 503,
 name: "My First Node",
 cluster_name: "Mycluster1",
 version: {
   number: "1.7.2",
   build_hash: "e43676b1385b8125d647f593f7202acbd816e8ec",
   build_timestamp: "2015-09-14T09:49:53Z",
   build_snapshot: false,
   lucene_version: "4.10.4"
 },
tagline: "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I tried adding this line in the config file but it did not bring a change.

```
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

I also restarted the elasticsearch but even that did not resolve my issue.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Error in log file:

```
[2016-09-01 08:58:09,755][INFO ][node] [My First Node] version[1.7.2], pid[1763], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
[2016-09-01 08:58:09,755][INFO ][node] [My First Node] initializing ...
[2016-09-01 08:58:09,850][INFO ][plugins] [My First Node] loaded [], sites []
[2016-09-01 08:58:13,090][WARN ][script] [My First Node] deprecated setting [script.disable_dynamic] is set, replace with fine-grained scripting settings (e.g. script.inline, script.indexed, script.file)
[2016-09-01 08:58:13,369][INFO ][node] [My First Node] initialized
[2016-09-01 08:58:13,369][INFO ][node] [My First Node] starting ...
[2016-09-01 08:58:13,541][INFO ][transport] [My First Node] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.80.2.185:9300]}
[2016-09-01 08:58:13,558][INFO ][discovery] [My First Node] Mycluster1/YN8RFw8uTVmWldavlau5Yg
[2016-09-01 08:58:36,469][WARN ][discovery] [My First Node] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
[2016-09-01 08:58:36,473][INFO ][http] [My First Node] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.80.2.185:9200]}
[2016-09-01 08:58:36,473][INFO ][node] [My First Node] started
[2016-09-01 08:59:06,704][WARN ][cluster.service] [My First Node] failed to reconnect to node [My First Node][YN8RFw8uTVmWldavlau5Yg][inet[/10.80.2.185:9300]]{data=false, master=false}
```

Comment: is there anything in the elasticsearch log files ?

Comment: @keety: I dont find elasticsearch.log file. In elasticsearch folder, I have only 3 files elasticsearch.yml, elasticsearch.yml.dpkg-old and logging.yml

Comment: `elasticsearch.yml` should have reference to the log directory .By default the path for logs is as [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html)

Comment: @keety: I have added the error message from the log file

Comment: The main error I see is "No known master node".

Comment: in the [config](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#master-node)  file do you have  `master` and `data` set to false ?

Comment: @keety: Yes it is set to false

Comment: yeah i'm assuming you are testting around with a one node cluster it should be safe to set it to` true` and try restarting

Comment: I tried setting it to true also, still getting the same error. Will it be a good choice to uninstall and reinstall elasticsearch

Comment: can you postyour `network.host` , `network.publish_host` setting in the config file  ?